# Finding subset where the value is equal to your value

Tags: r, floating-point, dataframe, subset

I am very new to R and trying to identify a specific row of data. I want the person whose `ideology` is equal to `0.085`. When I enter

```
subset(ideal112, ideology == 0.085)
```

I get

```
[1] name     state    cd       party    ideology

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since there is a data point whose `ideology` is `0.085`. When I type

```
subset(ideal112, ideology <= 0.085)
```

this data point shows up. However, I need to have R narrow it down to just where it is equal. I don't understand why the == isn't working. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is likely do to how floating point numbers are represented internally. So, instead of looking for an exact match, you should include some tolerance

This fails:

```
> a <- data.frame(x=rnorm(11), y=seq(0,1,.1))
> subset(a,y == .3)
[1] x y
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

This works

```
> subset(a, abs(y - .3) < .0001)
           x   y
4 0.04255609 0.3
```

Comment: It is important to find out why a number is inaccurate before recommending that people search with a tolerance. A tolerance introduces false positives that may cause bugs instead of remedying them. Also, even if a tolerance is appropriate, an absolute test is not appropriate for all situations. The errors involved might be absolute, relative to the final value, relative to some input values, or a complex function of multiple values. It is not good engineering to simple pick a value such as .0001 out of the air and compare it with an absolute difference.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the value in your data frame is not exactly equal to 0.085 (from you evidence you provide, it's likely slightly smaller than 0.085):

```
df = data.frame(x=0.0849999999)
df
#       x
# 1 0.085
```

As you can see, even though the actual value in the data frame is slightly less than 0.085, it pretty-prints to 0.085 when I output the data frame.

The code you provided in the post subsets to rows where your variable is exactly equal to 0.085. If you wanted to get rows that are very close (in this code, within 6 decimal places), try something like:

```
subset(df, round(x, digits=6) == 0.085)
#       x
# 1 0.085
```